# How can I apply a chain in Audacity only using the keyboard?

Tags: audacity

I can navigate most of Audacity's dialogs using only the keyboard, but I cannot find how to use the "Apply to Current Project" button from the "Apply Chain" dialog window.

I can move up or down to select the desired chain, but I cannot access the buttons at the bottom to apply it.

Is there something I'm missing or is it simply not implemented?

By the way, I'm using Audacity 2.1.3 on Mac

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone on a mac stumbles upon this issue, here's the solution : in `System Preferences / Keyboard`, in the `Shortcuts` tabs, change the `Full Keyboard Access` button from "Text boxes and lists only" to "All controls".

I can now exit the chain list with `TAB` and hit the `Apply` button.